# Getting data out of a promise

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, es6-promise, fetch-api

I know this question has been answered many times but something isn't quite clicking in any of the explanations.  I'm used to writing python so I'm pretty sure it's the async nature of promises that are eluding me.

I'm trying to make a simple get request and having a nightmare of a time.  For some reason no matter now many `return` instances I instantiate, nothing seems to actually evaluate and "unwrap" the promise object I'm being returned from my `fetch` call.  At this point I'm just trying to add more instances of `return`, `await`, or `async` because I'm clearly clueless as to what's going on under the hood.  Thanks for your time.

```
async function get_data(url){
  return await fetch(url);
}

function RetreivedList() {
  const get_url = "https://km4mqt2a5d.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/getList?URL=82ff68cce6444222be46ae1132d55cd8"; 
  console.log('making fetch...');    
  const foo = get_data(get_url).then(
    function(response) {
      return response.json()}).then(function(response){
    console.log(response.json())    
    return response;
      });


  console.log('heres the links!')

  console.log(foo);
  return(foo);
   };


console.log(RetreivedList());


RetreivedList().then(function(data){
  return(data.json())
});
```

codepen:https://codepen.io/dave-mitchell-the-looper/pen/JjYJjXq?editors=1112

Comment: For a start, you should call `.json()` exactly once. And you should place the `console.log` in the final callback - `RetreivedList().then(function(data){ console.log(data); })`

Comment: still returns ```[object Promise] {}```

Why did you think that would work?

Comment: Huh? No. The `data` passed to the `then` callback can *never* be a promise. But `console.log(response.json())`, `console.log(foo)` and `console.log(RetreivedList())` are all expected to log a promise. Drop them.

Comment: I don't get it.  In all the examples I see, that's ALL that gets passed to then.  Like this...

First example, in ```ComponentDidMount()``` method
https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html